# Excluding attributes entirely vs. setting them to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, comparative-review, python-requests

I am making a program that parses profiles from a website. Some profiles are "public" and others are "private" with limited information. Public profiles contain a lot more data and have ~15 more attributes.

Should I have one `Profile` class and set all unobtainable attributes to `None`? Or should I have 2 different classes and simply exclude unobtainable attributes if a profile is private?

**Option #1**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Profile:
    url: str 
    is_private: bool
    summary: str = None
    level: int = None


class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get_profile(self, url):
        resp = self.session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
        
        profile_is_private = bool(soup.find("div", {"class": "profile_private_info"}))

        if profile_is_private:
            return Profile(url=url, is_private=profile_is_private)

        summary=soup.find("div", {"class": "profile_summary"}).text,
        level=int(soup.find("span", {"class": "friendPlayerLevelNum"}).text)


        return Profile(url=url, is_private=profile_is_private, summary=summary, level=level)


parser = Parser()

public_profile = parser.get_profile("https://steamcommunity.com/id/afarnsworth")
print(public_profile)

private_profile = parser.get_profile("https://steamcommunity.com/id/private")
print(private_profile)
```

**Option #2**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BaseProfile:
    url: str 
    is_private: bool


@dataclass
class ExtendedProfile(BaseProfile):
    summary: str = None
    level: int = None


class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get_profile(self, url):
        resp = self.session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
        
        profile_is_private = bool(soup.find("div", {"class": "profile_private_info"}))

        if profile_is_private:
            return BaseProfile(url=url, is_private=profile_is_private)

        summary=soup.find("div", {"class": "profile_summary"}).text,
        level=int(soup.find("span", class_="friendPlayerLevelNum").text)


        return ExtendedProfile(url=url, is_private=profile_is_private, summary=summary, level=level)


parser = Parser()

public_profile = parser.get_profile("https://steamcommunity.com/id/afarnsworth")
print(public_profile)

private_profile = parser.get_profile("https://steamcommunity.com/id/private")
print(private_profile)
```

Both options seem to have downsides.

In **option #1**, the function returns a `Profile` object that might have over 15 attributes set to `None` because the profile was private and they couldn't be obtained.

In **option #2**, the function returns an entirely different object each time. So the user would have to manually check which object the function returned--either `BaseProfile` or `ExtendedProfile`

Which is better practice for a public API? Or are there better alternatives for these kind of designs.

Comment: Use #2. Your downside is not actually true. I'll explain in an answer in a bit.

Comment: But you should elaborate - what is the user doing with these objects that varies between the two types?

Comment: Your is_private is based on pseudocode. We cannot meaningfully answer questions that have pseudocode in them.

Comment: @Reinderien Nothing's different functionality wise. I'm using the dataclasses as a method of storing profile data.

I was initially going to give the profile class functions like `get_friends` and `get_comments` but instead decided to separate the profile object from the functions.

Also yeah I was going to include the entire code but just tried to make it less verbose. The `is_private` just parses the HTML and checks the profile's privacy status and stores it in a bool.

Comment: Can you include that, please?

Comment: @Reinderien I updated both code examples. Both should execute if you copy paste them. I haven't finished the program yet so it doesn't literally have all the attributes, but you can just imagine like 20 more (mix of both base profile attributes and public ones).

Also if it matters, not every profile has a summary. Some do and some don't, but to find out, the profile has to be public in the first place. So that's why everything in `ExtendedProfile` defaults to `None` since it's not guaranteed. But everything in `BaseProfile` is obtainable 100% of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely avoid #1. Something something [billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Research_and_career): if you don't need nulls, eliminate them.

Option #2 is okay-ish. Why are `summary` and `level` still nullable? First, as you have them, their typehint is incorrect because it would be `Optional[str]` instead; but I don't see how those would ever be `None` (that's the whole reason you're using #2).

Don't `bool(soup.find)`. Explicitly write `soup.find() is not None`.

`get_profile` should be hinted as `get_profile(self, url: str) -> Union[BaseProfile, ExtendedProfile]` - or use a pipe if you're fancy.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing is that some attributes in `ExtendedProfile` might not be always present. For example, maybe a user has an empty summary. But I suppose I could just do an empty string then.

Comment: For that, `Optional`s with `None`s are probably unavoidable